# Cant get heroku to link to my asset js/css in my rails app

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline

I'ved recently deployed my app on heroku, but for some reason, my scripts and css are not linked properly. In local there is no problem.

This is basically how I render my scripts and css in the view:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "welcome_page_scripts" %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "welcome_page_styles" %>
```

I'ved put these js/css files into vendor/javascripts or vendor/stylesheets directory.

In my production.rb:

```
   config.serve_static_assets = false
   config.assets.compile = false
```

I tried to set either one to true, and perform the following but still does not work.

```
rake assets:precompile --trace RAILS_ENV=production
```

Update 1:
(I noticed I also already have this in my Gemfile). Still the asset links not working on Heroku but works on local.

```
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
```

Can someone give me the right direction on how to solve this. Thanks.

Comment: I realized I also had this gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production in my Gemfile. Probably for this purpose previously but I dont know why its not working with my new js/css assets in vendor directory

Answer (score 0):

Did you remember to commit to git after you did the precompile (git add public/assets), and commit those changes to Heroku (git push heroku master), since the precompile creates a manifest.yml file in public/assets? More info here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline

Answer (score 0):

Heroku provides a gem for that. https://github.com/heroku/rails_12factor

If you don't want to use it, then going through issues in that page can be helpful

Comment: I noticed gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production is already in my Gemfile. I think I recall lastyear I bumped into this problem and had to do this. But now that I have new js/css assets, the new js/css links didnt work in Heroku. It works only on local.

Comment: Is there something I need to do besides including this gem ?

Comment: Have you added them into precompile? Like that: `config.assets.precompile << %w(welcome_page_scripts.js welcome_page_styles.css)`